# How to avoid byte[] for download of 4GB file

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm having problems downloading 4GB files with Spring Boot, because the byte array can't contain them (max 2.1GB).

I found various examples online on how to stream files, but I can't apply them to my specific case and would like advice on the way to follow.

In my case I receive a call from the Angular front-end telling me which file (4GB) I have to take from an external rest service (my current problem is here), and then I have to send it as a response to the Angular front-end (even zipped would be fine).

I currently do this when I call the external service. All work fine with small and medium file, but I get an error when the bytes exceed 2.1GB.
The error clearly says that a byte array has a maximum size of 2.1GB.

```java
WebClient wClient = buildWebClient(c.get(END_POINT));

byte[] file = wClient.get().uri("/v2/nodes/" + fileId + "/content").header("Ticket", ticket).exchange()
                    .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(ByteArrayResource.class))
                    .map(ByteArrayResource::getByteArray).block();

public WebClient buildWebClient(String endpoint) {
    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(endpoint).defaultCookie("cookieKey", "cookieValue")
            .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(-1))
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .defaultUriVariables(Collections.singletonMap("url", endpoint)).build();
}
```

I would like to find a solution that will allow me to do this avoiding the byte array, does anyone have any suggestions, probably using streams?

Comment: What is `wClient`? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You shouldn't convert to a ByteArrayResource, you should pump the bytes to the other side without storing or materializing in memory the entire response first.

Comment: @aled sorry, I added some code to clarify the doubt.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  Thank you! Could you kindly give me some links or some clues where to start?

Comment: Is `WebClient` the one from https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient.html? Please be explicit

Comment: Sorry, I don't have sufficient experience with Project Reactor and Spring Webclient to provide a full answer or links to solutions.

Comment: @aled yes, this is the weclient im referring to. the link you gave me seems to be a starting point, thanks. I'm going to do some tests to see if I can apply it to my needs.